# Logout button action not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue, viewcontroller

The context is, when a user taps the login button, application will check the credentials with web service, and if user is authorised the username and password are stored in userDefaults (for automatic login when user opens the application again)

Now i'm using a logout button on the next page (where the user goes after Successful login), and this is my code for that logout button which is not working.

According to me, on tap of logout, it should delete the userDefaults, and go back to login page. 
currently i'm not concerned about the appearance , just help me with the code.

Function for adding the button.

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.trash, target: nil, action: #selector(self.logoutButtonTapped(_:)));
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem;
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
```

Function for logout button :

```
func logoutButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userName")
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userPassword")
        let newViewObject = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginPageViewController") as! LoginPageViewController //LoginPageViewController is my login view file, and identifier also has the same name.
        navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewObject, animated: true)
    }
```

This is my storyboard. I'm adding button programmatically. 
[image]

Comment: can you show your stroyboard scene

Comment: Set the `target` to `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your Login VC as initial VC, then call in this place

```
let newViewObject = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginPageViewController") as! LoginPageViewController //LoginPageViewController is my login view file, and identifier also has the same name.
    navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewObject, animated: true)
```

use

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

else

```
  _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

**update answer**

```
 func logoutButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userName")
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userPassword")
         _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }
```

**for e.g**

```
  navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logoutButtonTapped))
```

and call the action like

```
 func logoutButtonTapped() {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userName")
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userPassword")

   // _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

     _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)



}
```

Comment: Sure i'll see that , i'll also try this answer. Thank you. :)
I've also updated my question with storyboard image.

Comment: can u sho ur sign in button action

Comment: Hey, i could not understand your answer.
I've been using iOS only for few days. Can u help little more.

Comment: @AshishSharma - sure, where u struck

Comment: Bro, I think the control is never reaching the logout action itself. Because, the user default are not getting deleted.

Comment: @AshishSharma - add the breakpoint and check , the logoutButtonTapped method is called or not, if it is called , the code is correct

Comment: I tried with breakpoints, it is never going to that logoutButtonTapped Action,  Yes the code seems to be fine only but it's not working.

Comment: @AshishSharmac- chek the example answer

Comment: @AshishSharma - can you show the button of login page VC `signinbutton` action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137263/discussion-between-ashish-sharma-and-anbu-karthik).